# how can I change appearance of alert from UINotification?

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

is there any way to change the outlook(appearance shape) of UINotification Alert, like I can insert image on UIAlertView, as below

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Status Update" message:myString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 100, 100)];

    NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"reminder_logo.png"]];
    UIImage *bkgImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [imageView setImage:bkgImg];
    [bkgImg release];
    [path release];

    [alert addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];
```

This code will show an image on UIAlertView. I want same thing for UINotification, but apple should accept it, because I can't alter their libraries, else rejection will happen from app store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local notifications are created and displayed by the system, not your app. Therefore you have no control over how they are presented.

Comment: that is what I already know, but I am asking any other way to manipulate with them?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can be any more clear. There is no way to manipulate them because they are not in your app. Short of jailbreaking the device and manually editing the assets that are used for the alert view there is no way to change it's appearance.

Comment: local notification title can be changed when app is opened, but couldn't when app is running is background.

Comment: The title has nothing to do with it's "outlook (appearance shape)" as you put it.